# Dynamically add control from base .NET

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio, visual-c++, controls

There is a way to add controls to WinForm from code. It is rather simple, for example:

```
Button ^btn = gcnew Button;

btn->Size.Width = 70;
btn->Size.Height = 30;
btn->Text = "test button";

this->Controls->Add(btn);
```

And we have a button. But when there are lot's of controls and lots of parameters for them, the code becomes too massive.

I used to work with an IDE that had a nice feature: you could create any type of controls in normal designer and set any preferences and methods for them, but they stored in a special base that you could connect in code and get any prepeared control from it.

Is there anything like this in Visual Studio?

Comment: Is the `User Control` the thing that you are asking for? You can add it by Add->New Item->UserControl. You can modify it with a designer and after you can add it to any form like a separate control.

Comment: Well, not quiet. UserControl is added with its frame and can contain several controls. What I need is a just same controls as in designer, but with already set preferences and view. But your suggestion gave me a good idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a while thinking and thanks to Sergey Schevchenko advise, I managed to create what is kinda similar to what I wanted.
Creating UserControl or just another form is not big difference. So I tried both ways.

So I created yet another form (or UserControl - same thing) called **"my_controls_form.h"** with several controls. And the main point is to make those controls **public** so that you could reach them from another form.

When designer create them it sets by default like this:

```
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^ my_button_btn;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^ my_label_lbl;
```

So I changed **private** to **public**, included this new form header in main form .cpp (`#include "my_controls_form.h"`) and then just added them to my main form like this:

```
my_controls_form ^frm = gcnew my_controls_form;
Button ^btn = frm->my_button_btn;
Label ^lbl = frm->my_label_lbl;

btn->Name = "__my_button";
btn->Location = Point(0,70);

lbl->Name = "__my_lalbel";
lbl->Location = Point(70,70);

this->Controls->Add(btn);
this->Controls->Add(lbl);
```

Still I have some doubts about this way. For example all methods for these controls are written in another class (form). 
And there is problem inserting control multiple times... Any ideas how to insert **several identical controls**?
*What else could go wrong*?